Need a PostgreSQL RLS policy for employees to see posts
I am using Supabase and PostgreSQL and have a number of tables as below:
Table 1: user_roles:: id, created_at, user_id, role_id

Table 2: roles:: id, created_at, role_name
id 1 >> admin
id 2 >> employer
id 3 >> employee

Table 3: porfiles:: id.....

Table 4: posts:: id, created_at, title, description....

I want to have a role on posts table so only employees can see the content.
The below code does not work:
alter policy "Enable select for employee role only"
ON posts
FOR SELECT
to public
using (
    EXISTS ( 
        SELECT 1
        FROM user_roles
            JOIN roles ON user_roles.role_id = roles.id
        WHERE user_roles.user_id = auth.uid() 
        AND roles.role_name = 'employee'
    )
);


Why a policy for update and delete if it is about seeing rows, which is select? Did you test the query in the exists claise? What exactly do you mean with "it doesn't work"? This question needs more clarity.

@LaurenzAlbe - Sorry just modified my question. It just does not return the result for the 'employee' user. More like the logged in user is does not have the right role to view content.

Did you test the query in the EXISTS clause? Does that return a result?
